# Getting rid of power button delay

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb

My goal is simple: Use the power button for other functionality. Unfortunately, Acer (Aspire V5 591G) 's power button comes with a delay. Meaning, pressing it is not enough. You have to press it for ~1.7s before anything happens.

Not even `xev` detects a key press before the delay. I tried remapping the key via `xkb`:

```
// (/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet)
// ...
key <POWR> { [ Prior ] }
```

works. (Interestingly enough, when holding it for 5 seconds, the OS commits suicide as usual though)

BUT the delay remains.

Is there a way to use the power key normally, like every other key? There is no bios setting for this key also. My fear is this might be a hardware implementation.

Comment: Hardware. If motivated, you could unwire the power button and then figure out how to wire it up to a USB keyboard controller that would then relay a button press as something...

Comment: Many laptops use an [Embedded controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller) for keyboard related things, very likely this is used for the delay. ECs are normally proprietary and undocumented, though ACPI describes some of the means to communicate with it. Reversing your EC and reprogramming it will be a substantial task.